# MVC Manage users access to specific controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authorization

We're busy porting a legacy ASP.NET web forms application to MVC. Some modules are finished with their valid `Authorize` attributes correctly set up, **but only 1 module is going live**.

So we must prevent the user from navigating to different modules (which are there, but not "live" yet). We don't want to meddle with the existing `Authorize` attributes, but users are currently not allowing access to these modules.

Here are my thoughts and shortfalls:

1. In `Global.asax` subscribe to `Application_AuthenticateRequest` and have a list of "Live" controllers, check the Request URL and throw and redirect to "Not Authorized page" if necessary. But how then I would would have to manually take **routing** into account where the URL may `mysite/` could route to `mysite/Foo/Bar/`.
2. Could the traditional `web.config` `authorization` be used for this scenario? (This would be easier to maintain than number 1, but the web is littered with **Don't do this in MVC**'s)

Something like this, where `Customer` is the controller:

```
<location path="Customer">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

3. Alternatively take the plunge, comment out ALL the `Authorize` attributes from the controllers which aren't live :( hoping not to go down this route...

Any push in a better direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Create a key in web config where you specify a list of controllers in Beta stage. Grab that list in another attribute like BetaAuthorizationAttribute and redirect your users somewhere http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1498727/asp-net-mvc-how-to-show-unauthorized-error-on-login-page or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20123589/how-to-restrict-access-to-certain-actions-in-controller-in-asp-net-mvc could be some reference for you

Comment: Thanks @RazvanDumitru, that's a fantastic idea. That would mean having to change the existing `Authorize` attributes unfortunately, but once done I can easily control access to live vs beta or controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the asp.net mvc filter on this case.

```
    public class YourCustomFilter : IFilterProvider
    {
        public IEnumerable<Filter> GetFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
        {
            List<Filter> result = new List<Filter>();

            var routeData = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData;
            var controller = routeData.GetRequiredString("controller");
            var action = routeData.GetRequiredString("action");

            if (controller != "livecontrollername" && action != "liveactionname")
            {
                result.Add(new Filter(new YourCustomAuthorizeAttribute(), FilterScope.Global, null));
            }

            return result;
        }
    }

    public class YourCustomAuthorizeAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
    { 
        //Do something to prevent user from accessing the controller here
    }
```

Then register this custom filter in Global.ascx, App_Start:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
     FilterProviders.Providers.Add(new YourCustomFilter());
}
```